# Where to keep long hardcoded data for initial migration in Django?

Tags: python, django, database-migration

I want to create two models something like this:

```
class LogActions(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default='-')
    text = models.TextField()


class Logs(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    log_message = models.ForeignKey(LogActions)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    price = models.CharField(default='-', max_length=20)
```

In LogActions there will be stored user actions. Example:

> Action one:
>
> name = 'USER_POINT_ADDED'
>
> text = 'User {user} added point to bla bla bla (long text...)'

There will be like 20 actions, names of this actions will be short, but texts are very long.

I don't know where to store all the initial data for migration... This data should be available through all project life.

I want to create dict like:

```
log_actions = {
    'USER_POINT_ADDED': 'User {user} added... <verylongtexthere>',
    'USER_POINT_EDITED': '<verylongtexthere>',
    'USER_POINT_DELETED': '<verylongtexthere>',
    'USER_GROUP_ADDED': '<verylongtexthere>',
}
```

All dicts like this above I hold in django settings.py file, but there are small and adding such a unclear hardcoded code to settings.py seems to be bad... but i need it for initial migration.

I'm Junior Dev are there any good habits in Django to store big hardcoded data that is needed to initial migration on new pc/server?

Did you met this kind of problem? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the FineManual: use fixtures.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/initial-data/